# Only the "Front Left" audio is working in Pop OS 22.04

Tags: drivers, audio, pop-os, pipewire, audio-volume

The right audio output is not working in Pop OS 22.04

Hello there, I did many attempts through these links and it's still not working.:

https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/uem5uk/unmet_dependencies_pulseaudio_pop_os_2204/

https://support.system76.com/

What do I need to do to get my right audio output working on Pop OS 22.04? I am using an Intel NUC i5 10th Generation with my Sceptre TV.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have qpwgraph installed? what do you see in qpwgraph? You may just have the right audio disconnected somehow.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/447981)